# C# Asp.Net.MVC - Como ler planilhas Excell (xls e xlsx) utilizando NPOI e gerar um datatable?

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel, npoi

Gostaria de ler uma planilha Excel(XLS e XLSX) em minha aplicação C#, utilizando a biblioteca NPOI e gerar um DataTable. Como nunca utilizei essa biblioteca alguém poderia me fornecer um exemplo prático?

Comment: Qual biblioteca é: tem como colar o endereço: NPOI

Comment: https://npoi.codeplex.com/